# Starting MySql Cluster ndb_mgm

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am trying to start maysql cluster ndb_mgm,

but its giving me the following error,
[image]

my my.ini file is like this,

```
[mysql_cluster]
# Options for management node process
config-file=C:/mysql/bin/config.ini
```

what is meant by unknown variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL Cluster global configuration file is by convention named `config.ini` (but this is not required). It is read by ndb_mgmd at startup and can be placed anywhere. Its location and name are specified by using `--config-file=path_name` on the `ndb_mgmd` command line. If the configuration file is not specified, ndb_mgmd by default tries to read a file named config.ini located in the current working directory .

```
# my.cnf
# example additions to my.cnf for MySQL Cluster
# provide location of cluster configuration file**
[ndb_mgmd]
config-file=/etc/config.ini
```

After saving the config.ini file, enter the following command to start the management server (the -f
option allows you to pass the location of the config.ini location):

```
ndb_mgmd -f /etc/config.ini
```

Start the management console by entering the following command:

```
ndb_mgm
```